# Append a list to a list of lists

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have been stuck on a problem. I tried to look for similar posts and could not find any, so my apologies if the question already exists.

I have a list of lists of the form

```
list = [[1], [2, 3], [4]]
```

And I'd like to append another list `[5, 6]` to it, to make it look like:

```
list = [[1], [2, 3], [4], [5, 6]]
```

But every time I tried a function of the sort append, or insert, the list became:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

instead.

I know this is quite an easy question but I can't find my way around it. I tried treating my list as a numpy array and then adding rows to it, but since all lists have different sizes, I can't do it unless by adding zeros to each rows to make them homogeneous, and this is not consistent with the rest of my program. So if anyone has an easy solution, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried. (btw, don't use `list` as a variable name. It is a built-in and should only be used to create lists).

Comment: You need to provide an example of what you tried and how it didn't work, a [mcve]. Also, Why is this tagged with `numpy`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely, if your code looks like this

```py
lst1 = [[1], [2, 3], [4]]

lst2 = [5, 6]

lst1.append(lst2)

print(lst1)
```

The output will be

```
[[1], [2, 3], [4], [5, 6]]
```

I don't know is this is what you tried, but if not, please have a look at this.

Comment: Hi, I think I might have figured it out. I did the same as you, and realized the reason it hadn't been working is because my lists were being treated as numpy array (because I'd defined them as such, and for some reason, the command np.append did not work the same way, and this had been what was the problem). Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: `np.append` is a poorly named cover for `np.concatenate`  It is not a list append clone.  The docs are worth reading.

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me:

```
>>> l
[[1, 2], [3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
>>> l.append([10,11])
>>> l
[[1, 2], [3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [10, 11]]
```

I am using python 3.6.3. 
The only thing I think you may not be doing is adding the square brackets in the append?

Comment: I had been, the problem was coming from numpy, but I have solved it. Thanks for your answer :)